# Dual space and kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Having X , a normed vector space and X* = B(X,R) its dual space ( R is the real numbers).
Show that for all f contained in X*, we have that Ker f included in X is a closed subspace.

Knowing that X* is a Banach space, since R is a complete space, does that make X a Banach space too ? 
Needing a little help with this one.

Comment: It is not necessary for $X$ to be a Banach space.  Indeed, however, $X^*$ will be a Banach space whether or not $X$ is complete (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131822/81360) for instance)

Comment: This answer really comes down to applying the definitions.  In particular: what does $\ker f$ mean, and what does it mean for a subspace to be closed?

Answer (score 1):

That $\ker f$ is a linear subspace is evident. To prove that it is closed, notice that $\ker f = f^{-1}(\{0\})$, which is the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ under the continuous map $f$.

This has nothing to do with $X$ being or not being a Banach space.